# Kind of passage to the limit in the sense of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory

Suppose $B$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $n>1$, and $f$ a locally integrable function. Suppose $F$ is a closed set with empty interior and $M>0$ such that the distribution defined by $f$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\int_{B\setminus F}f(t)\phi(t)dt\leq M 
\end{equation} for all test function $\phi$. We know that if we had 
$$f(x)\leq M$$ for all $x\in B\setminus F$, we could get the same inequality by passing to the limit (supposing that $f$ is continuous);  is it possible, in the same  way,  to circumvent around $F$ in (1) and prove that (1) holds for integrals over $B$?

Comment: Something is off in your formulation. The left-hand side of your inequality is linear with respect to $\phi$, and the right-hand side is not. Then again, does $M$ depend on $x$?

Comment: You are right! I got rid of $x$. How about it now?

Comment: it is better, but the point about $\phi$ being only on the left-hand side still stands.

Comment: Yes. Constant $M$ depends on $\varphi$.

Comment: Ok, how does $M$ depend on $\varphi$? This information is important. Imagine that $M = \|f\|_{L^1(B)} \|\varphi\|_\infty$, in this case your inequality has no new information at all.